# Stopping a conditional loop once the first TRUE condition is achieved

Tags: python, loops

I am running the following loop in python. However, I want the loop to stop once it finds the first condition that is TRUE. I do not want the whole loop executed if for instance the first condition is true.I want the rest of the loops ignore.

So far i am using `if`, `elif` and `else`. Please do you have any suggestions on how i can better handle this.

See sample code below

```
if report_sheet1.cell(107,154).value == '': ot = report_sheet1.cell(i + 8, 134 + j * 3).value
elif report_sheet1.cell(107,141).value == '': ot = report_sheet1.cell(i + 8, 121 + j * 3).value
elif report_sheet1.cell(107,128).value == '': ot = report_sheet1.cell(i + 8, 108 + j * 3).value 
elif report_sheet1.cell(107,115).value == '': ot = report_sheet1.cell(i + 8, 95 + j * 3).value 
elif report_sheet1.cell(107,102).value == '': ot = report_sheet1.cell(i + 8, 82 + j * 3).value 
else ot = report_sheet1.cell(i + 8, 69 + j * 3).value
```

Currently, the whole loop runs and the FALSE overrides conditions that are TRUE

Comment: This is what ```break``` is for. You can stop execution using ```break```

Comment: There is no loop in the code you've shown.

Comment: Could you show an example of the loop ? The question is a bit unclear.
Also, in general, if you want to break from some loop, it might help to look up the `break` statement, or if you just want to skip specific iterations of the loop, look into the `continue` statement.

Comment: Paste actual code, not screenshots!

Comment: @BogdanDoicin: Errrr.. you just removed pasted code and added a link!

Comment: @quamrana No. OP did.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin: Errrr... edit 6 shows that you removed text and replaced it with a link. What is going on?

Comment: @quamrana OP removed the code and wanted to replace it with a screenshot. But because he doesn't have enough rep, a funny text and an URL appeared instead of the image. I corrected that think and poof! the image appeared.

Comment: Ok, well, can you get the text back please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194253/discussion-between-bogdan-doicin-and-quamrana).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop the execution after the first condition is true, use the `break` statement after each test. The moment one condition is true, the program exists the entire structure.

I suggest to improve formatting of your code, as python cares about such a thing. I also suggest to keep practicing coding with the language, because loops are actually `for` and `while`, not `if`, `elif` or `else`.

Comment: My bad fam, am still very new to this.

Comment: It's okay. This is how you learn. If my answer was helpful, please mark is as accepted, so as other people get helped as well.